# Convert $\begin{bmatrix}a\\a+b+c\end{bmatrix}$ to coordinate basis $\{[1,0]^T [1,1]^T\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, change-of-basis

> Convert $\begin{bmatrix}a\\a+b+c\end{bmatrix}$ to coordinate basis $\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I don't know how to do this.

It looks like $\mathcal{e}_1$ has not changed, however $\mathcal{e}_2 = \mathcal{e}_1 +\mathcal{e}_2$

So does that mean:

$a\mathcal{e}_1 + (a+b+c)\mathcal{e}_2$

becomes

$a\mathcal{e}_1 + (a+b+c)(\mathcal{e}_1 + \mathcal{e}_2)$?

Comment: Let $v_1=e_1$ and $v_2=e_1+e_2$. You want to write $ae_1 + (a+b+c)e_2 = xv_1+yv_2$. If you expand the RHS, you get $$ ae_1 + (a+b+c)e_2 = xe_1 + y(e_1+ e_2).  $$ I guess you can take it from here?

Comment: You shouldn't think of $e_1$ and $e_2$ as changing. Those are the basis vectors for the **standard** basis, and only for that basis; writing something like "$e_2 = e_1 + e_2$" makes no sense. Rather, we are introducing a new basis we could call, say, $\{f_1, f_2\}$. It has $f_1 = e_1$ and $f_2 = e_1 + e_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_1=e_1$ and $v_2=e_1+e_2$. You want to write the vector $ae_1 + (a+b+c)e_2$ in your new basis $\{ v_1, v_2 \}$. This means, we want to express it in the following way (with $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$)
$$ae_1 + (a+b+c)e_2 = xv_1+yv_2.$$
So we need to solve for $x,y$. If you expand the RHS, you get $$ ae_1 + (a+b+c)e_2 = xe_1 + y(e_1+ e_2) = (x+y)e_1 + ye_2.  $$ I guess you can take it from here (remember that $\{ e_1, e_2 \}$ is a basis)?